# How to check if two strings are the same with an if statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

**Final Goal:** I am trying to make a javascript file that will hide everything on the page unless the url is contained in a blacklist.

**Todays Goal:** Use an if statement to check if the `currentLocation` variable is equal to a certain url. If it is do this code...If not do this code...

**What I have so far:**

```
var currentLocation = window.location;
if (currentLocation == "https://www.google.com") {
   document.documentElement.style = "display:none";
}
```

Comment: My answer works, I forgot `www.`

Comment: Not sure who down voted or why but please at least explain yourself as I am unable to post another question for 48 hours. This questions was on topic and worded properly. I don't see a reason why this was down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close. This is the corrected code. `window.location` is an object, you have to set condition on one of its key, for instance:

```js
if (window.location.origin === 'https://stacksnippets.net') {
  document.documentElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div>
  Something to show
</div>
```

Comment: https://stacksnippets.net needed to be "https://www.stacksnippets.net" but it worked! Thanks to all!

Comment: Use `console.log` on both `window.location` and `document.documentElement.style`. You'll get the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Will probably neeed some help tomorrow with arrays. But for now I’m set. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Use class and add this class to `document.body`

```
var currentLocation = window.location;
if (currentLocation.trim() === "https://www.google.com") {
   document.body.classList.add('hideAll');
}
```

CSS

```
.hideAll{
display:none
}
```

If css is not available then use inline style

```
document.body.style.display='none';
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I can't use an external css page for this project.

Comment: add these class in html page

Comment: I am not understanding. I am only allowed to use a javascript for this project.

Comment: Just did. Still not working. The if statement won't work. It doesn't think currentLocation equals "https:/.www.google.com"

Comment: `https:/.www.google.com` is wrong note `.` before `www...`

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't have any `ID` or `class`, you should use `body` tag. You can get `body` tag by using `getElementsByTagName` and make its display as `none`:

```
var currentHostLocation = window.location.hostname;
if (currentHostLocation == "google.com") {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.display = "none";
}
```

OR

```
var currentHostLocation = window.location.hostname;
if (currentHostLocation == "google.com") {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body").style = "display:none";
}
```

I believe, even this should work:

```
document.body.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Just tried the currentLocation.trim() . Unfortunately, it didn't work. display:none works. The problem is the if statement.

Comment: Updated my answer. You can remove the `trim()` and/or try option 2

Comment: that's very strange. Are you getting any error? It's strange because `document.body.style.display = "none";` should work unless it's not going inside the `if` condition.

Comment: It does work! But when in the if statement it doesn't. Therefore the if statement is the problem. Apparently I can't add more comments for some reason can you create another answer so I can continue to comment?

Comment: I believe `http` or `https` might be problem. I updated the code with `hostname`.

Comment: It didn't work. I can't add anymore comments. It says I need to create a chat. Can you please duplicate this answer so I can continue commenting.

Comment: `window.location.hostname` should give you domain name without the `http(s)` and that will fix the `if` condition. You can `alert(currentHostLocation)` to check.

Answer (score -1):

add a href method to window.location.  It is retuerning an object the way you have it, but with href it will return the href (address) as a string

```
     window.location.href
```

Comment: Tried: var currentLocation = window.location.toString;
if (currentLocation === "http://www.google.com") {
   document.documentElement.style = "display:none";
} but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, window.location.href

Answer (score -1):

You should get the current `hostname` and hide everything using below code:

```
var currentHostLocation = window.location.hostname;
alert(currentHostLocation);
if (currentHostLocation == "google.com") {
    document.body.style.display='none';
}
```